# Visual Studio Configuration Manager Misunderstand

Tags: visual-studio

I can not understand what use the "Configuration Manager" in visual studio. I 
continuously looked for some explanation / guide / documentation / sample but found nothing.

[image]

Please someone could provide me some link / brief explanation / sample on how to use this feature?

Comment: In VS, Help>>View Help>>Search "Configuration Manager Dialog Box"

Comment: Try to see if you can find some materials related to . sln file format. This dialog is the UI for you to edit some key data of that file.